# Bug in the calculation of unanswered % in Tag Info page

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

I noticed on multiple tag pages (on both SO and MSE) that the Last `7` Days percentage of unanswered questions is `0` for many tags. I checked the recent questions for such tags, and found unanswered questions.

For Example :

The [bug tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bug/topusers) says there are `36` questions in the Last `7` Days with `0%` unanswered.

While I don't know how often this page is updated, there are many unanswered questions on this tag from the past week:

**Date**:  **Unanswered Questions Posted on that date**

```
5/21 :  10
5/22 :  2
5/23 :  2
5/24 :  3
5/25 :  1
5/26 :  1
5/27 :  3
5/28 :  4 not including this question :)
```

On higher traffic tags (such as [PHP on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/topusers)), the percentage is non-zero, but still suspiciously low : `4,457 Last 7 Days 0.7% unanswered`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this situation at this time. I am seeing reasonable percentages when spot checking tags:

[image: Looks Good]

[image: Looks Good Also]

Perhaps a bug has been fixed between May 28 and now that I am not aware of. Sorry for the inconvenience!